# VSCode Run C/C++ File attempts to run the compiled program in WSL integrated terminal instead of CMD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've got a strange problem occurring when attempting to run a C++ program on VSCode. For examples sake, let's say I have the following main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I then go to compile and run the program using the `Run C/C++ File` button in the top right:

[image]

When I click this, the program is built successfully:

[image]

However, VSCode then attempts to run the built executable in the WSL integrated terminal instead of CMD, despite CMD being my default integrated terminal. This obviously throws an error:

[image]

After a few seconds, the following error message pops up:
[image]

My launch.json looks like this for reference:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: My guess would be you've installed a plugin which is doing this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue to my problem. For some strange reason, at the top of my User Settings (JSON), I had `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"`

I simply deleted the line and now everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to open the inbuilt terminal if it's not open, then click on the dropdown next to the "+" dymbol at the top right corner of the terminal, and click on "Configure Terminal Settings". In the tab that opens, set *Terminal › External: Windows Exec* to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Should do the trick. If it still doesn't work as expected, it might be an extension doing it, as Anthony said in the comments.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I un-installed all extensions too and am still faced with the same issue